# Next Refresh Date Visual in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I want to place a visual on the report which shows next refresh date. By 15th of every month to be precise. How to do that in power bi?

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

The refresh of a dataset is totally unrelated to the data shown. You can't foresee the future and predict when it will be refreshed. The only thing you can show is, when the refresh is planned. At any point in time you can change the refresh schedule, or manually refresh the dataset. So you can put a field showing the 15th of the current or next month, but it isn't guaranteed the next refresh will happen.

This can be easily done by a field in your database, or with DAX expression like this:

```
=IF(DAY(TODAY()) < 15,
     DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 15), 
     DATEADD(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 15), 1, month))
```